# Issue with backbone sub-routes when using with jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js, navigation

I have set up backbone.js and jquerymobile, with jqm hash routing turned off:

```
$(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.changePage.defaults.changeHash = false;
});
```

My backbone routes are set up as follows:

```
routes: {
  'news': 'showNews',
  'newsd/:nid': 'showNewsD'
}
```

My issue is that the url */index.html#news* works fine, but the url */index.html#newsd/23456* does not.

The */index.html#newsd/23456* gets handled by backbone, but afterwards jqm will try to handle the hash, causing error

```
GET http://myhost.com:4000/newsd/23456 404 (Not Found)
```

I am on jquery mobile 1.3.2.  Any clues?

Comment: you can remove appending the news id value in url and instead pass it using session storage? and keep the navigation simply like 'newsd': 'showNewsD', and once you do change page to showNewsD get the session value and do further processing ...

Comment: Thanks @Sheetal - your suggestion works.  However the downside is that there is no URL identifying the news item.

Comment: I'm also running into this issue. Is this a known problem with the $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false setting?